# Remove Javascript from PDF document using .NET Core

Tags: javascript, pdf, .net-core

I have PDFs sent in from an external source that I want users to be able to view via a web service.

The PDFs are retrieved via a .NET Core service that gets them from the DB and outputs them as PDF files.

The problem is that malicious users can put JS in PDFs. Because they appear to the browser to some from the same origin the JS can execute XSS attacks on the rest of the application.

I don't need to retain any of the JS functionality, but I also want to keep as much of the PDFs as unchanged as possible.

Is there a way, using .NET Core, to strip JS out of PDFs and leave them otherwise unchanged?

Alternatively is there any way to specify not to execute any JS when opening PDF files embedded in webpages (for instance using `<iframe src="file.pdf"` or `<object type="application/pdf" data="file.pdf"`). I can't rely on users having additional PDF extensions, it would need to work with the vanilla browser.

Comment: You can use any proper general purpose PDF library to remove js.

Comment: @mkl cool, post a functional example of one that works with .NET Core in an answer and you can have some rep.

Comment: Which is the .NET Core PDF library of your choice? I cannot recommend one because **A** I've not yet dealt with .NET Core at all and so have no experiences which PDF libraries work properly there, and **B** library recommendations are off-topic here...

Comment: @mkl ah, so you think I'm asking for product recommendations? Hence the down/close votes? While there are plenty of PDF libraries out there most are not compatible with .NET Core and only a subset of those can make the changes I'm asking about. Even then that is non-trivial (exposing the internals of the PDF file format is a long way from knowing what can be removed). I'm not asking which way is _best_, I'm asking whether it's even practically possible, and if it's so simple that any of many possible libraries can do it then please feel free to provide a library-agnostic answer.

Comment: Both Bobrovsky's and Mihai Iancu's answers explain how to do address the task, but as you see both of them advertise specific libraries in the process. So yes, your question in addition to help on a specific task effectively is asking for a library recommendation which in turn most likely triggered the down votes and close votes. (Neither was from me, I hoped to nudge you to declare a PDF library of choice... ;)

Comment: You will have to use a 3rd party library for this task because there is no built in support in .NET Core for processing PDF files.

Comment: @iPDFdev possibly, but the PDF format is pretty well known and the task achievable without accessing most of it. I live in hope :-)

Comment: @mkl yes, that's on them. Their answer: use my expensive library. Your answer: there's no way to do it without an expensive library. I wonder if anyone on here has a better way? If only there was some way to find out ;-)

Comment: *"Your answer: there's no way to do it without an expensive library."* - I'm not necessarily saying the library needs to be *expensive*... it simply must allow access to the JS entries, for reading and writing, either using high level APIs or low level direct access to individual PDF objects.

Comment: @Keith you can use an open source library if a paid one does not work for you :) PDF format is well documented but you still have to parse the entire file and build an object model in memory. You can go with a low level object model but you have to dig deep in the spec in order to know what objects to remove. Hours spent to write all this from scratch can be more expensive than an already written PDF library.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all the Javascript from PDF you could start from removing all shared JavaScript. This is a special document-level collection of scripts. It is often used to define JavaScript functions available for other scripts in the document.

Then you could find all actions in the document and check type of each of the actions. For Javascript actions you could replace associated code with an empty string.

This task is definitely not an easy one. I recommend you to use a PDF library for this.

My company develops [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) that can be used in .NET Standard / .NET Core and can help with your task.

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows how to remove the JavaScript code from a PDF file using [XFINIUM.PDF](http://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-crossplatform/xfinium-pdf-features.html) library:

```
public void RemoveDocumentJavascript(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream)
{
    PdfFixedDocument doc = new PdfFixedDocument(inputStream);
    // Remove document level JS code
    doc.JavaScriptBlocks.Clear();

    RemoveDocumentActions(doc);

    // Remove JavaScript from annotations.
    for (int i = 0; i < doc.Pages.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < doc.Pages[i].Annotations.Count; j++)
        {
            RemoveAnnotationActions(doc.Pages[i].Annotations[j]);
        }
    }

    // Remove Javascript from fields
    for (int i = 0; i < doc.Form.Fields.Count; i++)
    {
        RemoveFieldActions(doc.Form.Fields[i]);
    }

    doc.Save(outputStream);
}

private void RemoveDocumentActions(PdfFixedDocument doc)
{
    if (doc.OpenAction is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        doc.OpenAction = null;
    }
    if (doc.BeforeCloseAction is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        doc.BeforeCloseAction = null;
    }
    if (doc.BeforeSaveAction is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        doc.BeforeSaveAction = null;
    }
    if (doc.AfterSaveAction is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        doc.AfterSaveAction = null;
    }
    if (doc.BeforeSaveAction is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        doc.BeforeSaveAction = null;
    }
    if (doc.AfterSaveAction is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        doc.AfterSaveAction = null;
    }
    if (doc.BeforePrintAction is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        doc.BeforePrintAction = null;
    }
    if (doc.AfterPrintAction is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        doc.AfterPrintAction = null;
    }
}

private void RemoveAnnotationActions(PdfAnnotation annotation)
{
    if (annotation.PageOpen is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        annotation.PageOpen = null;
    }
    if (annotation.PageClose is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        annotation.PageClose = null;
    }
    if (annotation.PageVisible is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        annotation.PageVisible = null;
    }
    if (annotation.PageInvisible is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        annotation.PageInvisible = null;
    }
    if (annotation.MouseDown is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        annotation.MouseDown = null;
    }
    if (annotation.MouseUp is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        annotation.MouseUp = null;
    }
    if (annotation.MouseEnter is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        annotation.MouseEnter = null;
    }
    if (annotation.MouseLeave is PdfJavaScriptAction)
    {
        annotation.MouseLeave = null;
    }
    PdfLinkAnnotation link = annotation as PdfLinkAnnotation;
    if ((link != null) && (link.Action is PdfJavaScriptAction))
    {
        link.Action = null;
    }
}

private void RemoveFieldActions(PdfField field)
{
    field.CalculateAction = null;
    field.FormatAction = null;
    field.KeyPressAction = null;
    field.ValidateAction = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < field.Widgets.Count; i++)
    {
        if (field.Widgets[i].Focus is PdfJavaScriptAction)
        {
            field.Widgets[i].Focus = null;
        }
        if (field.Widgets[i].Blur is PdfJavaScriptAction)
        {
            field.Widgets[i].Blur = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The library supports .NET Core and it is available on nuget.org (id: xfinium.pdf.netcore).
Unless you implement your own PDF parsing and saving code, you cannot implement this task without using a 3rd party library.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops XFINIUM.PDF library.